# Argument of type 'typeof Store' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Store<AppState>'

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I'm trying to extend an angular service that uses `ngrx` and I'm getting this type error

```
Argument of type 'typeof Store' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Store<AppState>'
```

Here is my parent class:

```
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { AppState } from '../store/file-uploader.state';
import { AbstractStorage } from '@storage';

export class FileUploaderService {
    constructor(
        private store: Store<AppState>,
        private storage: AbstractStorage,
    ) { }
}
```

And my child class:

```
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { AppState } from '../store/file-uploader.state';
import { AbstractStorage } from '@storage';

export class DataSourceService extends FileUploaderService implements AbstractFileUploader  {
    constructor() {
        super(Store, AbstractStorage)
    }
}
```

I have to pass these 2 arguments to super. I've tried passing `Store<AppState>`, but it says it's using `Appstate` as a value, not a type. So I don't know how to type this arg. Does anyone know how to declare this super correctly?

Comment: did you try injecting Store<AppState> into the constructor of the child first and then passing it to super?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be passing the instances to `super` and not type. You can try below code and see if it helps:

```ts
    export class DataSourceService extends FileUploaderService implements AbstractFileUploader  {
      constructor(private store: Store<AppState>, private storage: AbstractStorage) {
          super(store, storage);
      }
    }
```